Option button doesn't work on macbook ubuntu
I have a MacBook with a japanese layout but when I press the option button it doesn't work on ubuntu 24.04

Question says 24.04 but you have tagged 22.04? What is the option button supposed to do? Most of use are not Mac users I think.

To get the backslash

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details.
